# Azure AD B2C integration with payment gateway

Tags: paypal, stripe-payments, azure-ad-b2c, payment-gateway

I'm building an application using Azure App Services and am using Azure AD B2C for the authentication. I'm currently only using local users with MFA, no social integration at this stage.

I need to restrict access to the app to only users who pay for a monthly subscription.

How can I integrate Azure AD B2C with a payment service provider like Stripe/PayPal? From what I've found so far this will require a custom user flow, but I can't find anything more specific.

Are there any sample projects I can refer to for this?

I've checked the Azure AD B2C github samples section at https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use REST API's to integrate, e.g. with Stripe. The API's are on their [developer page](https://stripe.com/docs/development).

There is a generic [B2C API sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/rest-api) to get you going.

Comment: Thank you for this. I think I'm close to understanding what I need to do. In the B2C API example you linkedrow 38 onwards seems to be defining what to send to their sample API:
https://github.com/enterprisebug/rest-api/blob/master/policy/SignUpOrSignin_WithValidation.xml

Then in the Stripe API reference to create a new subscription I just need to send a customer, price etc:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create?lang=curl

How would this be transposed into the B2C example above? As Input Claims?

Comment: It looks like JSON so use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/json-transformations